# Get content from raw.github and displaying on website

Tags: javascript

I am allowing members of a community to put the information they want on a web page made just for them, so I was wondering if it was possible to allow the user to use rawgitub (which just displays the text) and use that for them to change their info at will.

Looking around for something similar to this, I found the following, however, it seems to not work. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">setTimeout('read',30);function read(){  jQuery.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jordsta95/ArcaneArteries/master/aaversion.txt',function(data){document.write(data);});}</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout('read',30)` should be `setTimeout(read,30)`. setTimeout takes the function name as the first param, not a string of the function name. I don't know if it will correct the entire issue, but it is a start

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string to [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), it should be the function or a reference to the function:

```js
setTimeout(function read(){
      $.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jordsta95/ArcaneArteries/master/aaversion.txt', 
          function(data){
              document.write(data);
          }
      );
}, 30);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have this NOT fill the screen? It needs to be contained in a div

Comment: Yes, instead of document.write use $("#divName").append(data)